# Build ui.sref for a child state of a child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What I am trying to achieve:

In the template of the main state (/model), I have links to a child state phase (/phase), but I also want to be able to link from the main state directly to a given child state of a given phase (/phase/1/task1).

My config:

```
$stateProvider      
    .state('model', {
        url: '/model',
        views: {

            '': {
                templateUrl: 'model.tpl.html',
                controller: 'modelController'
            }
        },

    })

    .state('model.phase', {
        url: '/phase/{phaseId:int}',
        views: {
            '@main.model': {
                templateUrl: 'model.phase.tpl.html',
                controller: 'phaseController'
            }
        }            
    })

    .state('model.phase.task', {
        url: '/task/{taskId:int}',
        controller: 'taskController'
    })

};
```

In model.tpl.html I list out all the phases with general information, and for each phase, I list out tasks from that phase like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:{primary:true, knowledgeAreaId:area.id, phaseId:phase.id}:true" class="task" ng-class="{ active: task.active }">
   <div class="task__content" ui.sref="LINKHERE"></div>
</div>
```

And it is here I want to build a link that goes directly from the main model page to a given child page for a given phase.

What I have tried in model.tpl.html is to add ui.sref like so

```
<a ui.sref=".phase({ phaseId: task.phaseId}.task({ taskId: task.taskId})">
```

But that gives me an error, so it seems that you cant 'chain' states with properties.

If I only wanted to link to a phase, then the following works just fine:

```
<a ui.sref=".phase({ phaseId: task.phaseId}">
```

Is there any 'correct' soloution in ui.router for this scenario, or do I have to manually build a string for the href value. That way I change the url to the route I want instead of changing to a given state. It seems wrong to do that, when everything else works by switching states.

Something like:

```
http://localhost/#/model/phase/1/task1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
ui.sref=".phase.task({ phaseId: task.phaseId, taskId: task.taskId })"
```